# Glassfish Metro ClassCastException for SecurityHeader

Tags: java, wsdl, glassfish

I am using wsimport to generate my classes. At runtime I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBHeader cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.outgoing.SecurityHeader
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.listAddressByPostcode(Unknown Source)
    at uk.co.example.eaddress.EAddrServiceTest.directAddressTest(EAddrServiceTest.java:95)
    at uk.co.example.eaddress.EAddrServiceTest.main(EAddrServiceTest.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBHeader cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.outgoing.SecurityHeader
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.JAXBFilterProcessingContext.setJAXWSMessage(JAXBFilterProcessingContext.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage(SecurityTubeBase.java:383)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:247)
    ... 12 more
```

My pom.xml includes these dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have another wsdl generated service with the exact same dependencies, and when I check the pom dependency hierarchy in Eclipse they are identical. This other wsdl generated service works. I cannot see the difference between them.

I realise that this JAXBHeader should probably no be on the classpath, But I cannot find which jar it is in. Or if it is a matter of which order the class loader loads classes satisfying the same interface I cannot see how I exclude the JAXBHeader class. Other questions on this from a google search are from people who are  manually building these security header classes, mine is generated using wsimport.

Ideas?

Comment: I have found that the com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBHeader and the com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.outgoing.SecurityHeader it clashes with are both in the same webservices-rt.2.3.1.jar file. I cannot see how I can stop the classloader loading that class first. I also found an unanswered question of the same type on the metro mailing list.

Comment: I tried to post this on the metro user mailing list, after registering. I see in Nabble "This post has NOT been accepted by the mailing list yet. " I also see the same question asked here and never answered. https://java.net/projects/metro/lists/users/archive/2015-05/message/2

I get the feeling that Metro is not actively supported, their last release was over 3 years ago. The last version with source code available is 2009.